# Blender game recording at the wrong time

Tags: animation, game-engine

I have a simple animation for a midterm project; someone walks up and pushes dominoes over. I can set something with physics to knock the dominoes over at frame 125, then play the engine and he will walk up and push the dominoes up easy enough. When I record though, the animation will still show those things happening simultaneously, but the keyframes for the dominoes falling over are recorded at frame 270, a very long time after they're pushed over. How can I fix this?

Comment: (I think) you can use the dope sheet to select all the keyframes for all your dominoes, and move them closer to the beginning of your timeline.

Comment: @X-27thefluffyunicorn I'm just a first year student, so I guess they didn't think it was worth the time to teach me what the dope sheet was. Worked wonders, thank you!

Comment: Added an answer to make the question more useful. (I do not think comments are indexed in search engines). Feel free to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your issue is simply that all of your keyframes on the dominoes are starting too late, you can easily fix this by using the dope sheet. Select all of the keyframes in your scene by hitting <kbd>A</kbd> (or select just the ones you want by using box selection with <kbd>B</kbd>, or circle selection with <kbd>C</kbd>). Then simply move them closer to the beginning of your timeline. (shortcut would be <kbd>G</kbd>).

[image]